# Adding certain elements of list

Tags: python, list, sum

I want to add elements in a list every ten elements. For example:

```
a = [5, 31, 16, 31, 19, 5, 25, 34, 8, 13, 17, 17, 43, 9, 29, 41, 8, 24,
48, 1, 28, 20, 37, 40, 32, 35, 9, 36, 17, 46, 10, 30, 49, 28, 2, 3, 8,
11, 36, 20, 7, 24, 29, 15, 0, 4, 35, 11, 42, 7, 28, 40, 31, 45, 6, 45,
15, 27, 39,  6]
```

So I want to create a new list with the sum of every 10 elements, such as:

```
new = [187, 237, 300, 197, 174, 282]
```

Where the first entry corresponds to the add up of the first 10 numbers:

```
x = sum(5, 31, 16, 31, 19, 5, 25, 34, 8, 13)
x = 187
```

The second one to the 10 numbers in the range 10-19:

```
y = sum(17, 17, 43, 9, 29, 41, 8, 24, 48, 1)
y = 237
```

And so on; is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [25]: map(sum, zip(*[iter(a)]*10))
Out[25]: [187, 237, 300, 197, 174, 282]
```

Comment: Well done. Where, or how, did you learn about the `zip(*[iter(a)]*10)`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` on an iterator of the list:

```
>>> it = iter(a)
>>> map(lambda *x: sum(x), *(it,)*10)
[187, 237, 300, 197, 174, 282]
```

Create an iterator for your list. Pass the items to `map` in 10s using the iterator and use `map` to return the `sum` of the passed parameters.

Python 3.x will require an explicit `list` call on `map`

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested comprehensions with a list iterator:

```
i= iter(a)
s= [sum(next(i) for _ in range(10)) for _ in range(len(a)//10)]
print s
```

Note that this will silently ignore any leftover values:

```
a= [1]*11 #<- list has 11 elements
i= iter(a)
s= [sum(next(i) for _ in range(10)) for _ in range(len(a)//10)]
print s
# output: [10]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about list comprehension, like this one:

```
>>> step = 10
>>> 
>>> [sum(a[x:x+step]) for x in range(0, len(a), step)]
[187, 237, 300, 197, 174, 282]
```